# How to setting build different theme with ng or npm command

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm try to use different npm command to build different theme liks npm run red (it will start index with red.html) or npm run blue (it will start index with blue.html)

[npm run red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR4R3.png)
[npm run blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyuPF.png)

I'm setting in package.json wiht

```
"red": "ng build --configuration red",
"blue": "ng build --configuration blue",
```

and angular.json like this

```
        "red": {
          "index": "src/app/redComponent.html"
        },
        "blue": {
          "index": "./src/app/blueComponent.html"
        },
```

but if i run the command it's will show error

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAttribute')

Answer (score 0):

You should add some configurations

```
{
  "projects": {
    "name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "red": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/index.html",
                  "with": "src/app/redComponent.html"
                }
              ],
            },
            "blue": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/index.html",
                  "with": "src/app/blueComponent.html"
                }
              ],
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then in your package.json :

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "red": "ng build --configuration=red",
    "blue": "ng build --configuration=blue",
}
```